# CDF for the linear combination of p Gumbel random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**I'd like to know if there is an article or any insights to derive the exact CDF for the linear combination of p Gumbel random variables, as it was shown for the PDF in this [article](https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00207160701536370).**

Let $Z = \alpha_1X_1+\alpha_2X_2+...+\alpha_p X_p $ denote the linear combination where $X_j$ are independent Gumbel random variables given by the probability density functions (pdfs):

$$f_{x_j}=\frac{1}{\sigma_j}\exp{\bigg(-\frac{x-\mu_j}{\sigma_j}\bigg)}\exp{\bigg[-\exp{\bigg(-\frac{x-\mu_j}{\sigma_j}\bigg)}\bigg] }. $$

for $x$, $\alpha_j$,$\mu_j$ $\in [-\infty,\infty]$ and $\sigma_j>0$.

The [article](https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00207160701536370) show that the exact PDF for $Z$ is

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}\exp{\bigg[it\bigg(\sum^{p}_{j=1}\alpha_j \mu_j-z\bigg)\bigg]}\prod^{p}_{j=1}\Gamma(1-i \alpha_j \alpha_j t)dt$$

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/462433/119261.